# Should a WCF service be instantiated when bringing up the wsdl?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am upgrading .NET 4.0 IIS hosted WCF services to VS15 and .NET 4.6.  I noticed that my service blows up under 4.6 when I navigate to http://server/service.svc because OperationContext.Current is null.  After a little debugging I noticed that under my .NET 4.0 solution the service is not actually instantiated when navigated to via the browser to pull the wsdl, therefor that code never hits.  Under 4.6 it seems the service is instantiated.  The obvious solution is to check for OperationContext.Current to be null, I am just wondering if perhaps I am missing something bigger.

So in short are those two behaviors expected due to some changes between the two version of the framework?

Comment: Could you please share some more details regarding to the issue? E.g. some repro code, config, or how/where you use the OperationContext.Current.